# How to put "*" and "**" after each occurrence of the word "EUR"

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I starting with Jasper Studio.
I have a string "666 EUR / 699 EUR"
I want to put "*" after first occurrence of the word "EUR" and "**" after second occurance of the "EUR"

Actaully: 666 EUR / 699 EUR.
I want to: 666 EUR* / 699 EUR**.
Another want to: 8888* / 333**.

I'm trying with something like:

```
.contains(EUR)? "**":"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
"666 EUR / 699 EUR".replaceAll("EUR", "EUR*").replaceAll("\\*$", "**")
```

or

```
$F{myVariable}.replaceAll("EUR", "EUR*").replaceAll("\\*$", "**")
```

and

```
"8888 / 333".replaceAll("([0-9]) ", "$1* ").replaceAll("$", "**")
```

[image: jasper image]

Comment: Instead of second replace, you can just concatenate with * like this "666 EUR / 699 EUR".replaceAll("EUR", "EUR*") + "*"